# Save an image from a div background-image url in plain javascript no jquery etc

Tags: javascript

I found posts on this topic but most examples are jQuery based how can I save an image from a div background-image url

```js
/*????*/
```

```css
.x{
  background-color: red;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='x' style='background-image: url(https://wallpapertag.com/wallpaper/full/c/4/1/145845-grand-canyon-wallpaper-1920x1200-for-android.jpg);'></div>
<div class='x' style='background-image: url(https://de.zopix.net/image_upload/117969-landschaften-sunset-evening-clouds.jpg);'></div>
<div class='x' style='background-image: url(http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/Sunset-Village-Wallpaper.jpg);'></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _how can I save an image from a div background-image url_ ? do you want to remove it from `background-image` property and add as an `img` tag ?

Comment: Open your browser's debugger. Go to the Network tab, select IMAGES. Reload the page. You can see all of the images in the page. Right click - open in new tab, right-click, save.

Comment: I don't think my website visitors will want to do that many people are use to just right clicking or drag and dropping to save an image. If you don't know how it's ok I appreciated that you responded to me.

Comment: Why not use an `img` tag?

Comment: This might help you:https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/comment-page-2/#comments

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, then you could do the following:

1. Extract the image URL from the style of the element that is being processed
2. Create a temporary anchor element (used to trigger a download)
3. Assign the image URL as the anchor elements `href` attribute
4. Add the anchor to the docuemnt, invoke it's click action (to trigger download)
5. Clean up by removing the temporary anchor from your document

So, something like this should work for you:

```js
function downloadBackgroundImage(element) {
  
  // get the backgroundImage of the passed DOM element
  const backgroundImage = element.style.backgroundImage;
  
  // sanitize the backgroundImage style value by removing url(..)
  // to get a value suitable for the href attribute below
  const imageURL = backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
  
  // extract image filename for download attribute
  const imageFilename = imageURL.slice(imageURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  
  // create a temporary anchor element and set the href attribute
  // and add it to our DOM
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("href", imageURL);
  a.setAttribute("download", imageFilename);
  
  document.body.appendChild(a);

  // invoke the click behavior to trigger download
  a.click();

  // housekeeping - remove the temporary anchor element
  a.remove();  
}


downloadBackgroundImage( document.querySelector('.x') )
```

```html
<div class='x' style='background-image: url(https://wallpapertag.com/wallpaper/full/c/4/1/145845-grand-canyon-wallpaper-1920x1200-for-android.jpg);'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this keeps on redirecting me to the image src I dont want that I want to be able to right click on any of those divs and save its image source

Comment: as a image to my desktop as an image file

Comment: @ThomasWayne may be a case of the missing "download" attribute - does the updated answer work for you?

Comment: Once you're on the source URL you can right click and save as

Comment: No it does not sorry @DacreDenny it keeps on redirecting to the image source I want to be able to stay on the same page of my code page not the image src.

Comment: it keeps sending me to this link https://wallpapertag.com/wallpaper/full/c/4/1/145845-grand-canyon-wallpaper-1920x1200-for-android.jpg